# FreeForm Pro 4.1.3 / EE 2.7.3 javascript issue

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Upgraded EE to 2.7.3 and installed FreeForm Pro 4.1.3. When creating a new field, I can't add the field to any forms. The javascript doesn't fire because the javascript isn't included in the file. The JS file edit_field_cp.min is actually commented out in mpc.freeform.php on line 990 and 3212. If I uncomment (therefore gets added), it throws JS errors.

Is this a problem for anyone else? Insight? Thoughts?

Updated: added screenshot:
[image: New Field form]

Comment: Did you upload the themes folder that comes with Freeform? Is it possible to see a screenshot of the "New Field" form in your CP?

Comment: Yes. Edited original post to display screenshot.

Comment: Well, turns out the files I was given were not from the original download. All seems well now. Thanks.